# How to select objects of a model related to my model

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm creating a filtering system for my application and I would like to render `<select>` fields, pre-filled with options possible.

Lets assume I have a model called `Exam` which has relation to `Student` and this has relation to `StudentProfile` - I'm filtering `Exam` objects by field `has_scholarship` in student's profile so I'm creating a query such as: `student__student_profile_has_scholarship` and passing it to django's filter() function and it works.

Now however, I'd like to render html form with  and all possible `<option>`s, to do so I need to find the mentioned possible options. **How can I find all objects from such a query string as above to get all the objects of `student__student_profile` from my `Exam` model?** This also has to work regardless of how long the chain of relations is assuming the relations are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are models:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    example = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")


class Stydent(models.Model):
    exam = models.ManyToManyField(Exam, related_name="students")


class StydentProfile(models.Model):
    stud = models.ForeignKey(Stydent, related_name="profiles",
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
```

If it is: Get all Students or Profiles from `exam`:

```
In [27]: exam
Out[26]: <Exam: Exam object (1)>

In [27]: exam.students.all()
Out[28]: <QuerySet [<Stydent: Stydent object (1)>]>

In [29]: exam.students.model.objects.all()
Out[29]: <QuerySet [<Stydent: Stydent object (1)>, <Stydent: Stydent object (2)>]>

In [30]: exam.students.model.profiles.field.model.objects.all()
Out[30]: <QuerySet [<StydentProfile: StydentProfile object (2)>, <StydentProfile: StydentProfile object (1)>]>
```